# Swagger codegen with multiple swagger json

Tags: swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate nodejs client sdk using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
Here is the command I use

```
swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l javascript -o ./petstore
```

But for the actual sdk which I need to generate the swagger spec is split in two different json files and I want to create a single sdk for both. How can I do this with Swagger-codegen, using multiple swagger json at same time?

Comment: Split how? Are they separate definitions, or does one file $ref the other one?

Comment: Hi Helen, they are two different files

Comment: Hi @Sandy I'm also having similar problem, I need to generete definitions/classes from more then two json input. Any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Reuse the `--input-spec` option (or `-i`) for every location of the swagger spec, as URL or file.

Comment: Specifying multiple `-i` arguments seems to make the code generator ignore all but the last.